# Does Perl's /m regex modifier match differently on Windows?

Tags: windows, regex, perl, multiline

The following Perl statements behave identically on Unixish machines.  Do they behave differently on Windows?  If yes, is it because of the magic \n?

```
  split m/\015\012/ms, $http_msg;
  split m/\015\012/s, $http_msg;
```

I got a [failure](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.cpan.testers/2008/10/msg2450019.html) on one of my CPAN modules from a Win32 smoke tester.  It looks like it's an \r\n vs \n issue.  One change I made recently was to add //m to my regexes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For these regexes:

> ```
> m/\015\012/ms
> m/\015\012/s
> ```

Both /m and /s are meaningless.

- /s: makes `.` match `\n` too.
  Your regex doesn't contain `.`
- /m: makes `^` and `$` match next to embedded `\n` in the string.
  Your regex contains no `^` nor `$`, or their synonyms.

What is possible is indeed if your input handle (socket?) works in text mode, the `\r` (`\015`) characters will have been deleted on Windows.

So, what to do? I suggest making the `\015` characters optional, and split against

```
/\015?\012/
```

No need for /m, /s or even the leading `m//`. Those are just cargo cult.

Comment: ARGH!  I think you're right and I was on the wrong track with the regex modifiers.  I'm using `` to get input from a subprocess and never thought to worry about binmode...

Answer (score 3):

There is no magic `\n`. Both `\n` and `\r` always mean exactly one character, and on all ASCII-based platforms that is `\cJ` and `\cM` respectively. (The exceptions are EBCDIC platforms (for obvious reasons) and MacOS Classic (where `\n` and `\r` both mean `\cM`).)

The magic that happens on Windows is that when doing I/O through a file handle that is marked as being in text mode, `\r\n` is translated to `\n` upon reading and vice versa upon writing. (Also, `\cZ` is taken to mean end-of-file – surprise!) This is done at the C runtime library layer.

**You need to [`binmode`](http://p3rl.org/binmode) your socket to fix that.**

You should also remove the `/s` and `/m` modifiers from your pattern: since you do not use the meta-characters whose behaviour they modify (`.` and the `^`/`$` pair, respectively), they do nothing – cargo cult.

Answer (score 1):

Why did you add the `/m`? Are you trying to split on line? To do that with `/m` you need to use either `^` or `$` in the regex:

```
my @lines = split /^/m, $big_string;
```

However, if you want to treat a big string as lines, just open a filehandle on a reference to the scalar:

```
open my $string_fh, '<', \ $big_string;
while( <$string_fh> ) {
    ... process a line
    }
```